# Show alert after all requirements have been met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where the user can 1.) check one option and be done. or 2.) check the other option and fill out a text field.

Whole thing is, after all is said and done I'd like for my alert to show, but it doesn't.

```
$('.know-your-role').show('fast', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox.checkchoice');
    if($checkboxes.is(':checked')){
        // show this after checked and the input has been filled.
        alert('cool');
    }else if($checkboxes.is(':checked') & $(".year").va() != "" ){
        alert('cool');
    }
});
```

How do I get the alert to show after all requirements (checkboxes and input) have been met? 
I've made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg8jT/9/) to show what I'm working with.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the previous correct answers (missing `&` and misspelled `val`) there is a more fundamental logical issue here.  You seem to have this structure:

```
if (conditionA) {
    // behaviorA
} else  if (conditionA && conditionB) {
    // behaviorB
}
```

You will never reach behaviorB with such logic.  If `conditionA` fails then `conditionA && conditionB` will certainly also fail.

Do you need to reverse the order of your `if` and `else-if` blocks?

Comment: You're right about the logic part. But even when reversing the order of the conditions http://jsfiddle.net/Jg8jT/10/ . I'm left with the same problem.

Comment: Is there a way to implement an OR || senario: `if (conditionA && conditionB) {
// do this
} or (conditionA){
// do that
}`  ?

Comment: How about `if (conditionA && !conditionB) { // behaviorA } else if (conditionA && conditionB) { // behaviorB }`?

Answer (score 0):

Missing '&'

```
$checkboxes.is(':checked') && $(".year").val() != ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&&` instead of `&` for boolean comparisons, and also you appear to have mis-typed `val` as `va`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having two events, one on the 'Teacher' check box being checked and one on the year field being completed. Both events can trigger a single function that shows your alert and whatever other logic you want. So there is little duplication.

This helps to separate the events from the logic that shows/hides the year field and more easily allows you to perform different actions for the two events if that's a requirement.